# Deploy definition confusion

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat

what's the exact meaning of the word "Deployment" in case of Tomcat. Is it just putting any Servlet or JSP file in the web app folder correctly, or I'm still forgetting anything important here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, deployment in case of java web applications is the last stage after building and packaging the app. In this level, it would be just ready for deployment, hence, it's ready to put and run on the server. So in case of Tomcat, it's copied to the deployment web folder so tomcat will be able to pick it up, extracting it (if needs to) and runs it. I hear you question btw, it's been so confusing at first and it might different from one application server (or container) to another but in the end, its the process to make the app up and running or at least, ready to be up and running at any time.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Anddo's answer, in case of tomcat, you need to tell it to rescan the directory webapps to pick it up and start. And yes this will load/reload the classes even container managed classes like Servlets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell Tomcat to rescan the directory or refresh the webapps or something. It won't pick it up on its own and start running it, unless it is there when it was started.

You can do this from the tomcat manager page.

Comment: So 'Deployment' actual meaning is to reload the classes too, before accepting any request for a class in a Container. Am I right?